# Stencil JS not working with non-default imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, babylonjs, stenciljs

I'm using BabylonJS in a StencilJS app, and I can only seem to import in a very specific way.

For instance I can't do:

```
import { Engine, Scene } from "babylonjs";
```

It says `'Engine' is not exported by node_modules\babylonjs\babylon.js`
But it is..

I can do:

```
import BABYLON from 'babylonjs';
```

and use it like

```
private _scene: BABYLON.Scene;
```

I'd like for the former to work. Any advice?

The first way is how most tutorials do it, and I refuse to believe SencilJS is just not capable of that. I must be missing something

Comment: Seems similar to fixed issues like here https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/issues/4391

Comment: Which version of Babylon do you use?

Comment: @SergeyMell I was using babylon 3.3 Apparently this normally works there. However, after upgrading to 4.x, I am able to do imports a bit more like I would expect here. Although barely, https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/es6_support#installing-babylonjs

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get in what exactly you had gotten an issue. Could you provide package.json of your project? At least some kind of short version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BabylonJS](https://www.babylonjs.com/) is provided in two versions ([ES5](https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/npm_support) and [ES6](https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/es6_support)). The issue you are referring to is related to ES5 version of package.

If you do smth like this in your code

```
import * as babylon from 'babylonjs';
console.log(babylon);
```

and look into the console, you will see next:

> `{default: Module, __moduleExports: Module, babylonjs: undefined}`

That's why decomposition is not working, it's not an object that can be serialized the way you expect.

In documentation they say

> import { Engine, Scene } from 'babylonjs';
>
> NOTE: if you can't make this import method to work, go to the section on typescript and webpack below.

However, I failed to make it work for ES5 version. The correct way, as to me would be to use ES6 version of package, which can be installed as

```
npm install -S @babylonjs/core
```

This version allows you to use ES6 packages together with tree shaking and other useful features.

Your module import, in this case, would look exactly as you wish:

```
import {Engine, HemisphericLight, Mesh, Scene} from '@babylonjs/core';
```

Here is a [small example](https://github.com/SergeyMell/stencil-experiments) I've done to prove my words.

Please, let me know if I got you wrong and you expected to have smth different or you need some additional explanations or materials - I'll be happy to assist.